# How to toggle arrow position in select input when selected?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm making a select input component. What I need to do now is that when I click on select, the arrow is pointing up, and when I click out the arrow is pointing down (which is how it is already).

I already managed to put a custom arrow, but I can't make the arrow toogle, to be pointed either up or down.

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-moon-fdrd8y?file=/src/styles.css)

Can you tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40%;
  width: 350px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* select starting stylings ------------------------------*/
.select {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}

.select-text {
  position: relative;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: right 0.7em top 50%, 0 0;
  background-size: 0.65em auto, 100%;
}

/* Remove focus */
.select-text:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Use custom arrow */
.select .select-text {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  content: "";
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* LABEL ======================================= */
.select-label {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
.select-text:focus ~ .select-label,
.select-text:valid ~ .select-label {
  top: -20px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: "50px"
      }}
    >
      <div class="select">
        <select class="select-text" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected></option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label class="select-label">Select</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep it just with css or you can add some javascript to your project ?

Comment: Hi SKJ, just with CSS, I can't use JS in this case